# Show that this mapping (with respect to basis) is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $B = \{b_1, b_2,...,b_n\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the map taking $[v]_B$ to $[T(v)]_B$ is a linear transformation from  $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. This linear transformation is represented by a matrix $[T]_B$.

---

I only need to prove that $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$ and $T(αv) = αT(v)$ are true for it to be a linear transformation. But, I can't come up with any relation between $[v]_B$ and $[T(v)]_B$ that look anything close to that. Maybe with $[v]_B = $ a bunch of scalars, I could set that as $α$?

And apparently, there is some "change of basis" matrix involved with when multiplied with $[v]_B$ will give me $v$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $[v]_B \mapsto [T(v)]_B$ can be written as
$$
[v]_B \mapsto v \mapsto T(v) \mapsto [T(v)]_B
$$
It suffices to show that the map taking $v$ to its coordinate vector $[v]_B$ is an invertible linear transformation, so that the map that you're looking at is simply the composition of linear maps (and hence linear).